# wrap std::iterator in C++

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a need to wrap a vector iterator, but don't like the idea to rewrite it from scratch. And I can't subclass it as far as vector iterator doesn't seem to be cross-platform. At least gnu and ibm ones look different.

What I want to do is the following:

```
class MyContainer {
    vector<double> data;
    vector<int> indices;

    iterator
    begin()
    { return my_iterator(data, indices.begin()); }

    iterator
    end()
    { return my_iterator(data, indices.end()); }
}

MyContainer  cont;
```

Where indices vector contains integer positions within the data vector. Data is supposed to be much much bigger than the indices.

So I need an iterator that can go through the indices in any direction like a normal vector iterator does with the only exception: it must return a value of data vector when the value is going to be accessed. e.g.:

```
for(MyContainer::iterator it = cont.begin(); it != cont.end(); it++) {
    cout << *it << endl; // values of data should appear here
}
```

Basically it should look like a normal collection for the std world. You can iterate it in whatever direction you want, you can sort it, run unique, find_if, etc...

any simple solution?

Comment: If I understand, you really have a vector of doubles and the indices vector is pointless. Or maybe I'm wrong, I'm not getting a clear impression of what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: I have two vectors. One contains a big dataset (10k elements). Indices will point to a subset in dataset. Like this: indices = {1, 2, 5, 1000};  I want to iterate through the container as if I would do it over the indices vector, but the values that are returned must be taken from data vector.

Comment: @birryee, my guess is is that the values in the `indices` vector are actually indexes in to the `data` vector and that he wants to output the value of the `data` vector at the current index referenced by the iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks a lot like a [permutation_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/iterator/doc/permutation_iterator.html), one of the "built in" adapters from the [Boost.Iterator Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html#specialized-adaptors)

See [this example](http://codepad.org/FIjZ5FO8) (modified from the Boost docs) on codepad.

Comment: Similar, but `permutation_iterator` permutes a continuous range of indices. OP wants more of a `combination_iterator` (if it existed) so zhe can skip some indices.

Comment: @outis: I don't believe that the range of indices has to be continuous. Look at the example at the bottom of the page. "indices" is a `list<int>` which only happens to be filled with contiguous numbers in the example, but could contain anything else.

Comment: @outis: I created an example with non-contiguous indices on codepad. See the link in my answer.

Comment: @Éric: you're right. I was going off the text in the introduction.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. permutation_iterator is exactly what I was going to need

Answer (score 6):

There's a great Boost library for defining custom iterators. You need to provide a class with a few methods:

```
i.dereference()  Access the value referred to
i.equal(j)       Compare for equality with j
i.increment()    Advance by one position
i.decrement()    Retreat by one position
i.advance(n)     Advance by n positions
i.distance_to(j) Measure the distance to j
```

Then you get the rest from the [iterator_facade](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html).

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the standard C++ library, but you can probably get [`boost::iterator_adapter`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_adaptor.html) to do what you want. A preliminary examination suggests you'll need to override `iterator_adapter::dereference` and `iterator_adapter::equal`.

```
template <typename _Scalar=double,
          typename _Idx=int, 
          typename _Seq=std::vector<_Scalar>, 
          typename _IdxVector=std::vector<_Idx> >
class SelIter 
    : public boost::iterator_adaptor< SelIter<_Scalar, _Idx>, 
                                      typename _IdxVector::iterator, _Scalar > 
{
public:
    typedef boost::iterator_adaptor< SelIter, typename _IdxVector::iterator, _Scalar > Base;

    SelIter(_Seq& scalars, _IdxVector& idxs);
    SelIter(_Seq& scalars, typename _IdxVector::iterator pi);

    typename Base::reference dereference() const;
    bool equal(const SelIter& x) const;
private:
    // ...
}
```